# Magento sales/order collection with filter: where orderid not in

Tags: magento

I'm working with this collection:

```
$salesCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$salesCollection->getSelect()->order('entity_id DESC')->limit( $num_orders );
```

Is it possible to add a filter to the query, which works like `WHERE OrderID NOT IN ('100001','1000002','100003')`?

I've tried it with AddFilterToField(), but it doesn't work :-/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code,  `100001,100002 are   orders ids` .But 1`00001,100002 are   increment_id of orders` .Please check sales_flat_order table.

Try the below

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToFilter('increment_id', array('neq' => array(10001,1002)))
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('increment_id',DESC);
```

Comment: never use addAttributeToSelect('*') if you dont need it. its a performance killer.

Comment: @mischa,Thanks  for your advice